# Images arent shown in my collectionviewcells. iOS(swift)

Tags: ios, swift, image, core-data, collectionview

I got an array with all the images i got from the camera. They are saved in my coreData. If a user takes a new photo, the photo will be saved in the core data and then i replace the normal array data with the coreData images. So if i go back to the collection view, only the first and the last image is shown. When i print the images[indexpath.item] out i got the images. But they arent shown in the cells. I have a custom class for the imageView in the cell and the imageView has constraints, so the image cant be out of the visible area i think.
I look forward to solve this problem with your help. Thank you.

Here is the code from camera catch :

```
 func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage!, editingInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]!) {




    photoImage.image = image

    print(images)
    addPhotoLabel.removeFromSuperview()
    if(isEdit == false)
    {

        let context = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext
        let entinity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Image", inManagedObjectContext: context)

        let newImage = Image(entity: entinity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: context)
        newImage.image = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1)
        do {
            try context.save()
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error)
        }
        images.removeAll()
        let request = NSFetchRequest()
        request.entity = entinity
        let fetched = try? context.executeFetchRequest(request)
        if fetched != nil {
            let imagesS = fetched!.map { UIImage(data: ($0 as! Image).image!)}

            images.appendContentsOf(imagesS)

        }




    }
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil);
}
```

And here is the code were i create the cell :

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
//1

let cell : FlickrPhotoCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! FlickrPhotoCell





if(searchBarActive == true)
{
    cell.nameLabel.text = researchResults[indexPath.item]
    cell.imageView.image = sFunc_imageFixOrientation(resultImages[indexPath.item])



}
else
{


cell.nameLabel.text = names[indexPath.item]
    let imageT : UIImage = images[indexPath.item]!

cell.imageView.image = images[indexPath.item]
print(images[indexPath.item])




}

cell.nameLabel.hidden = false

cell.frame.size = CGSizeMake(UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width/2  , UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width/2)

cell.imageView.frame = cell.frame



cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
cell.layer.borderColor = themeColor.CGColor
cell.layer.borderWidth = 4
cell.layer.cornerRadius = CGFloat(10.0)
cell.placeHolderName.frame.size = CGSize(width: cell.frame.width, height: cell.frame.height/4)







return cell
```

}

Comment: Please show us the code that you have try.

Comment: here is the source code if you need more just ask, Thank you @NDoc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you try and change: `cell.imageView.frame = cell.frame` to `cell.imageView.frame.size = cell.frame.size`

Comment: You are my hero men !